# implement Samsung allshare in android studio app

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an existing app that i am developing in android studio. I want to integrate Allshare in it , from the [`http://developer.samsung.com/allshare-framework`](http://developer.samsung.com/allshare-framework) I can see how to use their plugin for eclipse. I dont want to use eclipse.so my question is "How to start with `Samsung allshare` in `Android studio`?"

Comment: no one knows about allshare cast on this forum or what???  I posted a topic regarding to this, but no one has commented anything yet.